# How to make proper form of media queries?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am trying to make my website look adaptive for both smartphones and desktops. There're Chart and Info blocks. I want them to be positioned across the width on desktops and laptops, and one above the other on the mobiles. But Chart goes into first block at the small mobile width. What can I do here?

[image: mobiles].

It already looks nice and good at desktops.

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 1281px) {
  /* ??? */
}
```

```html
<div class="justify-content-flex-start" style="margin-top: 10px; padding-left: 0%; padding-right: 1%;margin-left:15%; min-width: 320px; max-width: 1281px;">
  <div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px; padding-left: 1%; padding-right: 1%;">
</div>
</div> <!-- First block -->

 <div class="container" style="width: 360px; margin-top: 10px; padding-left: 1%; padding-right: 1%; padding-bottom: 10%; margin-right: 25%">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="./src/js/graph.js"></script>
<div id="FlexCGraph justify-content: center" ><iframe class="chartjs-hidden-iframe" style="display: block; overflow: hidden; border: 0px; margin: 0px; inset: 0px; height: 100%; width: 100%; position: absolute; pointer-events: none; z-index: -1;" src=></iframe>
<canvas id="global-speed-chart" style="display: block; height: 250px; width: 100%; padding-right: 1%; margin-right: -8%; margin-top: -78%; padding-bottom: 5%; padding-top: 1%;"></canvas>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Chart -->
```

```
@media (min-width: 1920px) {
 .dashboard {
   padding: 15px;
   display: -webkit-box;
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: flex;
   position: relative;
   -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
       flex-wrap: nowrap;
   -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
   -webkit-box-direction: normal;
       -ms-flex-direction: row;
           flex-direction: row;
           align-items:center;
           align-content: center;
           justify-content: flex-end;
 }
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 360px) {
 .dashboard__desc {
   display: -webkit-box;
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: flex;
   width: 100%;
   position: relative;
   -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
       flex-wrap: nowrap;
   -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
   -webkit-box-direction: normal;
       -ms-flex-direction: row;
           flex-direction: row;
   padding-top: 10px;
   align-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: flex-start;
 }
}
   @media only screen and (min-device-width: 360px){
.crypto-card{
 width: 360px;
 height: 215px;
 background: white;
 right: 40px;
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 10px;
 border: 0.1px solid rgb(220, 220, 220);
 max-width: 360px;
 align-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 360px){
.row{
 align-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 360px){
.crypto-card .body{
 width: 100%;
 padding: 20px;
 margin: 2px;
 font-size: -0.4rem;
 font-family: 'Myriad Pro', sans-serif;
 position: relative;
 top: 5px;
 align-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
}
}
#FlexCGraph
{
 align-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: flex-end;
 position: absolute;
 padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
 margin: auto;
 width: 360px;
 height: 215px;
  max-width: 360px;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  -webkit-align-self: auto;
  align-self: auto;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0.1px solid rgb(220, 220, 220);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
#wb_FlexCGraph
{
 align-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: flex-end;
 padding-left: 10%;
  visibility: visible;
  display: block;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  -webkit-align-self: auto;
  align-self: auto;
}
}
```

Comment: Please put all relevant code into a single snippet demo using the editor so we can see what you're talking about. Be sure to include the CSS that presumably goes in your media query block. See [ask] and take the [tour] for tips.

Comment: Protip: No one likes working with inline styles. You have classes there, so use them for your CSS. It's much easier to debug and to maintain.

Comment: I get the impression from some of those class names that you're using a layout library. That's critical information for us to know also.